# Rails 4 and AJAX: How to have AJAX change the URL, so reloading still keeps the same js.erb file and user can properly use back/forward buttons

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails 4 app, how can I use AJAX so page result changes what the user sees without reloading (normal AJAX stuff), AND (i) if they then reload the url they see the same result and (ii) they can hit the back button to go to the previous page, and, from there, the forward button to come back to AJAX created page. Basically, so the page appears to act like a "normally" loaded page?

I have reviewed stuff like Railscasts 136, 240, and 246, and stack overflow like [pushState with Rails ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031483/pushstate-with-rails-ajax), to build the following simple code for AJAX loading a post:

```
config/routes.rb
  ....
  resources :posts

views/posts/index.html.erb:

 <h2> Posts </h2>
 <div id="all-posts">
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <div id="show-single-post"><%=link_to post.title, remote: true %></div>
   <% end %>
 </div>

views/posts/show.js.erb:

  $('#all-posts').hide().after('<%= j render('show_form') %>');

views/posts/_show_form.html.erb:

  <h3> Here is the post you clicked on </h3>
  <h3><%= @post.title %> </h3>
  <h4><%= @post.text %></h4>

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

  class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
   @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

--this renders the show view on the index page without reloading. However, URL has not changed. To try and change URL:

```
app/assets/javascripts/index.js

   $(document).on('click', '.requestshow [data-remote=true]', function() {
     history.changeState(null, '', $(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
   });

  $(window).on('popstate', function () {
    $.get(document.location.href)
  });
```

--This code changes the url to /posts/1. BUT: When the user hits refresh, the posts/1 url looks for a different file--show.html.erb. And if the user clicks on one post ("Post 1"), then goes back to the index and clicks on another post ( "Post 2"), the Post 1 view seems to stay in the cache, so that, from Post 2, if you hit back, it takes you not to the index, but to the Post 2 show.js.erb view. Using replaceState addresses this, but then messes up the back button (sends all the way back to home page, not index page).

Comment: This question is just far too long. Please scale it down to generate a problem overview a lot sooner and get rid of unnecessary discussion

Comment: Like @charlietfl says, TL:DR, but, i think that the solution to your problem is to use **url fragments** which are the part after the `#` in a url.  These can be read from and written to by javascript and allow you to create a deeplink to the modified version of your page.  Have a look at this http://www.codemag.com/Article/1301091

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at the url fragments article. I have cut the original question down a bit (sorry for it still being long, wanted to be clear on the issues that were coming up)