# Ruby on Rails AJAX changing URL and copy / paste it from browser address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've created a simple admin panel with a menu that uses Rails remote responces.
The typical link is like this:

```
<%= link_to t('my-groups'), :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'mygroups', :remote => true %>
```

The controller action for it is this:

```
  def mygroups
    if request.xhr?

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
       end
    else 
      redirect_to :dashboard
    end
  end #end mygroups
```

I also have a partial called _mygroups.html.erb and a js.erb file called mygroups.js.erb with the following contents

```
$('.right_col').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'mygroups')) %>");
```

It all works fine and the partial page is dynamically loaded inside my main template just like it's supposed to.
What I want though is to be able to use browser history to navigate through these results, and also to be able to copy the URL from browser's address bar and get to the same dynamically loaded content if I paste the URL to my browser's address bar by hand and hit enter.

For example, if I click "dashboard/mygroups" menu link it would load _mygroups partial, change the url to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/mygroups and push state to the browser's history. And if I just insert this url to the address bar, it would load the main template and then load _mygroups partial to its internal div container. This is the kind of behavior I want from it.

The only solution I see, is to use simple page reload without "remote" links. But I know a lot of websites (e.g. github.com) which use AJAX and allow to copy/paste URL from address bar

How can I implement the same behavior with Rails? 
Maybe my whole concept is wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031483/pushstate-with-rails-ajax)?

Comment: Of course. I'd googled before asking here. I'm using a different scenario. It's not pure AJAX call, but Rails remote link with response to js file. I just can't figure out how to solve this